# Html: Bring Image to front of page

Tags: html, image, position

I have been awarded the task with my basic Html skills to bring the image i have highlighted in yellow to the font.

[Image of task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv8xH.png)

From what i can see, it is sitting behind this specific class #movie (Video frame) and i can not figure how i may bring it to the very font keeping that absolute position.

This is what i have so far in terms of code positioning and pulling the image:

```
<p style="width:40px; position:absolute; left:0em; top:30em;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">

<img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/jv6e7q.png" "style=width:80px; margin-left:50px; margin-top:50px;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"  ></img> 

</p>
```

The html tags available for use are:

a p i strong b u ul ol li h1 h2 h3 img font br

I thank you in advice for your help! It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the `z-index` property to the `img`.

```
<img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/jv6e7q.png" style="z-index: 10; width:80px; margin-left:50px; margin-top:50px;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"  ></img>
```

Comment: Thank you for this info but adding z-index to this property removes this property completely from webpage. Any other suggestions?

Comment: EDIT:

This video box does not have an index, not from what is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Check Here, it is working with minor modification and use of z-index

See this fiddle

```
<p style="width:40px; position:absolute; left:0em; top:30em;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aman9753/owycbkhp/1/

Comment: Thank you for the above. I know it was working and it actually appears everywhere on the page except above that specific window.

I have tired the z-index as mentioned by a previous person but i can not find the correct z-index (using firefox dev tool) or even if one exists..